# How to show two separate subdocuments in same result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to join 2 subdocuments in a result?

Example:

I have publishers and the publishes have packages and books for sell.
What i want is to show only the packages they want to sell.

Here is my publishers document:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId('1')
   name: "Publisher name 1"
   ...
   packages : [{
      _id: ObjectId('p111'),
      books: [2222, 3333] //Books IDs
   },{
      _id: ObjectId('p222'),
      books: [4444, 5555] //Books IDs
   }],
   books: [{
      _id: ObjectId('2222'),
      name: "Book 2"
   },{
      _id: ObjectId('3333'),
      name: "Book 3"
   }, 
   ...
   ]
}
```

The query:
`Publisher.find({_id: 1}, {packages: 1}...);`

What i want is this result:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('1')
   name: "Publisher name 1"
   ...
   packages : [{
      _id: ObjectId('p111'),
      books: [{
      _id: ObjectId('2222'),
      name: "Book 2"
   }, {
      _id: ObjectId('3333'),
      name: "Book 3"
   }] //Books IDs
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code from the [website](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) I think it solves your purpose. You can customize the solution for your problem.

```
Person
.find({ occupation: /host/ })
.where('name.last').equals('Ghost')
.where('age').gt(17).lt(66)
.where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking'])
.limit(10)
.sort('-occupation')
.select('name occupation')
.exec(callback);
```